# Quartz scheduler logs via log4net coming in wrong log file

Tags: log4net, .net-4.5, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, log4net-configuration

I have two projects: one (MyApp.QuartzImplementation) where all initialization and quartz job related working is done while another project (MyApp.XYZApi) do other stuff.

I have separate log4net logs files for each project. The problem I am having is that the scheduler related logs are coming in my main project (MyApp.XYZApi) logs though I have initialized the scheduler from another project (MyApp.QuartzImplementation).

Sample logs which are coming in Main project log files are

```
2018-05-10 17:01:06.034 INFO    TANG_DM N1  16              StdSchedulerFactory.Log     Quartz scheduler 'DBScheduler' initialized
2018-05-10 17:01:06.050 INFO    TANG_DM N1  16              StdSchedulerFactory.Log     Quartz scheduler version: 3.0.4.0
2018-05-10 17:01:06.087 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  16              SimpleSemaphore.Log     Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: 75af30b2-9658-4b61-b2ca-6bf3d74f6486
2018-05-10 17:01:06.087 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  16              SimpleSemaphore.Log     Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: 75af30b2-9658-4b61-b2ca-6bf3d74f6486
2018-05-10 17:01:06.103 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  16              SimpleSemaphore.Log     Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' given to: 75af30b2-9658-4b61-b2ca-6bf3d74f6486
2018-05-10 17:01:06.119 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  15              DeviceDataManager.StartOtpExpiryJob     Sleeping For 1 Hours
2018-05-10 17:01:06.188 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  16              SQL.Log     Prepared SQL: UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = @newState WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'DBScheduler' AND (TRIGGER_STATE = @oldState1 OR TRIGGER_STATE = @oldState2)
2018-05-10 17:01:06.266 DEBUG   TANG_DM N1  16              SQL.Log     Prepared SQL: UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = @newState WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'DBScheduler' AND (TRIGGER_STATE = @oldState1 OR TRIGGER_STATE = @oldState2)
2018-05-10 17:01:06.272 INFO    TANG_DM N1  16              JobStoreTX.Log      Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.
2018
```

My log4net config looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>  
  <appender name="MyAppXYZApi" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="..\\Logs\\XYZ_DM_N1" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}&#9;%p&#9;XYZ_DM&#9;N1&#9;%t&#9;%property{ExternalIP}&#9;%property{ContextId}&#9;%property{ContextValue}&#9;%c{1}.%M&#9;%property{SessionId}&#9;%m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="QuartzScheduling" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="..\\Logs\\XYZ_QuartzScheduling_N1" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}&#9;%p&#9;XYZ_QuartzScheduling&#9;N1&#9;%t&#9;%property{ExternalIP}&#9;%property{ContextId}&#9;%property{ContextValue}&#9;%c{1}.%M&#9;%property{SessionId}&#9;%m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppXYZApi" />
  </root>
  <logger additivity="false" name="MyApp.XYZApi">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="MyAppXYZApi" />
  </logger> 
  <logger additivity="false" name="MyApp.QuartzImplementation">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="QuartzScheduling" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

Please let me know if i can do any things for scheduler logs of quartz to be written to particular log file

When i have added %logger as suggested following are the quartz namespaces in the logs

```
Quartz.Util.DBConnectionManager 
Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory 
Quartz.Simpl.TaskSchedulingThreadPool 
Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl 
Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate 
Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler 
Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SimpleSemaphore 
Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.MisfireHandler 
Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread 
Quartz.SQL 
Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX
```

Can i some how put all of them in one single appender

Comment: If you have two separate log4net files, why does the one you show contain both appenders? Also, are you sure that your scheduler related log entries are all being called from methods in the namespace MyApp.QuartzImplementation?

Comment: What i have shared is an example. I have windows service project on which has three separate log files logging. One is for some logging in My Starting windows service project (like logging start/stop/ what things are enables related thing).  One project is for pure quartz related calls. infact one more project for handling some separate business. only problem is backend quartz checking logs are coming in the log file of my starting project

Comment: You could try adding `%logger` to your Layout to check what the  namespace is for these calls.

Comment: thanks sgmoore. please check my edited question about what namespaces of quartz i am getting in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to change

```
<logger additivity="false" name="MyApp.QuartzImplementation">
```

to

```
<logger additivity="false" name="Quartz">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sgmoore